# Population Ethics references

Tags: ethics

I'm looking for references on population ethics, preferably those with a mathematical bent. Broome's [Weighing Lives](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0199297703) is a good example of what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that Diamond and Koopmans have booth done some interesting work in this area. The blog post [Kill the young people](http://philosophyforprogrammers.blogspot.com/2012/11/why-old-people-matter-more.html) has a discussion of Diamond's paper, and Koopmans' "Stationary Ordinal Utility and Impatience" can be found [here](http://hassler-j.iies.su.se/Courses/NewPrefs/Papers%5CKoopmans%20Ec%20Apr%2060.pdf).

Basically, they investigate the idea of "impatience" (valuing things which come earlier more) and show that under some reasonable conditions, population ethics must be impatient, a very counter-intuitive finding. It is often mentioned in the context of environmental ethics.